# In terms of temperature, how can you tell if food is thawed?

Tags: thawing

I am planning to place a meal (salmon + rice) in the refrigerator to thaw it.

I will use a thermometer to check if the food is thawed. What is the temperature range for when the meal has been successfully thawed?

Comment: @moscafj lol. I what is the ideal temperature for thawed food - is it between 0C - 4C?

Comment: Ideal for what?  There is no ideal.  It is either thawed or frozen. You can store it between 0C and 4C (plenty of info on this site for how long)...cook or reheat.  I'm really not sure what you need beyond that.

Comment: The thawed food will no longer be frozen (-> >= 0°C) and just have the same temperature as your refrigerator.